# Jquery select on key property

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery to do a select on an object that is generated by a third party control.

Here is the HTML

```
      <th id="x:2115528574.12:adr:0:idx:0:key:ViewPACDetailTemplateDataField:hdr:1:skp:"                    
      class="" style="width: 161px;" title="" skp="" hdr="1" 
 key="ViewPACDetailTemplateDataField" idx="0" adr="0"></th>
```

Any way that I can use jquery to select all of these that have the     key="ViewPACDetailTemplateDataField"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
$('th[key="ViewPACDetailTemplateDataField"]');
```

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) you can find other jQuery's Attribute selectors.